# Switching threads or doing work on I/O thread is more costly?

Tags: multithreading, rx-java, rx-java2

```
repository.data
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.map { data <- 'do some computations' ... }
.subscribe()
```

Is it better in this case to switch to the **Computational Scheduler**, before doing the `map` operation (`.observeOn(Schedulers.computation()`)?

What if we are *observing* **multiple sources** that *depend* on each other? Like getting **data1**, *mapping* it, then getting **data2** based on **data1**, then again *mapping it*. In this case we'd have to change threads between *every **computational** operation* and **data request**.

Comment: Staying on the `io` thread can become a problem when there are more IO activities and subsequent computations than CPU cores.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight answer for this question. You have to consider it always for specific case. Although there are some rules you can follow, based on this knowledge:

1. Computation thread pool has maximum number of threads and the size is based on device that you use. Most commonly used is a pool of 4 threads.
2. IO thread pool is basically unlimited, meaning if you start 100 operations at the same time, there will be 100 threads created, so be carefully with its usage.
3. Switching a thread can always creates some drop in performance, because its additional operator and it can be forced to wait in the queue.
4. The real question is: is this task so heavy that I have to switch thread? In most of the cases a network call or database call takes the most time and other operators are very quick. Simple mapping or iterating through array of 1000 elements is basically done in an instant.
5. Another question is: am I performing so many tasks in the background that I have to free this thread? Will it really help something? Is someone waiting for this Scheduler to free some thread?

Those are rules from the top of my head. There is something that I may forgot, but generally those steps help you decide if you have to switch thread. Hope it helps :)